# Containing NA values loop calculation

Tags: r, loops, na

I have a numerical sequence containing `NA`. There are at least two continuous values that are not `NA`, like this:

```
x
# [1]   2 4 NA NA  1 NA  1  2 NA NA
```

I try to do this

```
y[1]=1, y[2]=y[1]*(x[2]/x[1])
```

When there is `NA`

```
y[i]=y[i-1]

g<-function(v){
  t=v
  for(i in 2:(length(v)-1))
  { if(!(is.na(v[i])))
    v[i+1]=v[i]*(t[i+1]/t[i])
  else v[i]=v[i-1]
  }
}
```

This function doesn't not work. Besides I try to apply the function to a  large matrix by column, it works too slow for g have loops.

Do you have better way to do this?

Comment: Please add the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want `y` to remain unchanged when the ratio of the `x`s is missing, you can calculate the ratio of the `x`s, then fill in the missing values with `1` and keep right on mulitplying using the function `cumprod()`.  Without a `for` loop, I'm guessing this would be faster than the function you were using.

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  # calculate the ratio of x[i] to x[i-1]
  xrat <- x[-1]/x[-length(x)]
  # when the ratio is missing, define it as 1
  xrat[is.na(xrat)] <- 1
  # define y
  y <- c(1, cumprod(xrat))
  return(y)
}

# your x
x <- c(2, 4, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA)
y <- myfun(x)
```

The results look like this

```
cbind(x, y)
       x y
 [1,]  2 1
 [2,]  4 2
 [3,] NA 2
 [4,] NA 2
 [5,]  1 2
 [6,] NA 2
 [7,]  1 2
 [8,]  2 4
 [9,] NA 4
[10,] NA 4
```